# wrong path after url re-write

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following code in ht access

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^outsource.example.com/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/outsource/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that the link http://outsource.example.com/packages.php

is not redirecting to http://www.example.com/packages.php

i want the same redirection on other links to

Comment: I think tha last '/' in the first RewriteCond should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Considering:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^outsource.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/outsource/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Will result into the following:

```
 > GET http://outsource.example.com/packages.php 
 < 301 http://example.com/outsource/packages.php 
 > GET http://example.com/outsource/packages.php 
 < 301 http://www.example.com/outsource/packages.php 
 > GET http://www.example.com/outsource/packages.php 
 < 404 - since your file seem to be at /packages.php
```

You should reduce the number of redirects and change your path:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^outsource.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will result into:

```
 > GET http://outsource.example.com/packages.php 
 < 301 http://www.example.com/packages.php 
 > GET http://www.example.com/packages.php 
 < 200 - and the content of your packages.php
```

Comment: plz give the solution again